# Intelligent JavaScript contextMenu

Tags: php, javascript, html, contextmenu, getelementbyid

I'm creating a desktop based file sharing system, and I need a way to use a contextmenu to delete and interact with the files. It needs to be able to know what file has been clicked on, etc.

```
      <?php if ($dirs = @opendir($path)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dirs)) !== false) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            ?>
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="<?php echo $path."/".$file?>" >
                    <div class="ico <?php include('includes/php/ext_check.php');?>"></div>
                    <?php echo " ".$file?>
                </a>
                <!--<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deleteOption('<?php echo $path."/".$file?>');">
                    delete
                </a>-->
            </div>
<?php }}
    closedir($dirs);
    }
?>
```

That is the code that shows the file, and the commented out line is the code to delete the file. I need to be able to include that line of delete in a context menu. 
Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if i got your intent here..

But lets says.. when user clicks on some thing in context menu you want to show corresponding option  like if its possible to delete that file context menu should show delete option else it should not..

if above is what you need.. you can add your own attribute to your tag like

```
<div myAttribute="delete|something" ></div>
```

choose some unique attribute name and when it gets clicked you can have the attribute value and show items accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean this: http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-context-menu-tutorial.htm